# Angular 2 - Child Component Not Inheriting Styling from Parent Component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular2-template

I have a Parent Component which uses Child Component. I wrote the necessary stylings in Parent Css file and the styling will change accordingly when we hover over the div. The Child Component is not accessing the Parent Component's styling classes.

There's one solution to do this, using `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` , but when i use it, my whole styling is getting disturbed.

Is there any other way to do it?

Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/gwcTi4QyZyFPtlgfY5Al?p=preview

Child Component:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'testapp',
    template: `
      <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    `
})
export class TestApp{   
}
```

Parent Component:
Html code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="test">
<testapp></testapp>  
</div>
</div>
```

Parent Component: CSS code:

```
.container{
  font-family:sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.test{
  width:50%;
  background-color:#f0f5f5;
}

.container:hover .test{
  background-color:#e6ffe6;
}
.container:hover .test:hover{
  background-color:#ffffe6;
}
.container .test a {
    color:   red ;
}
.container .test a:hover {
    color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move the styles to the child component and pass a class name from the parent to the child.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector:'testapp',
    template: `
      <a [ngClass]="anchorClass" href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
    `,
    styles: [`
        a.red-green-anchor {color:red;}
        a.red-green-anchor:hover {color:green;}
        a.orange-blue-anchor {color:orange;}
        a.orange-blue-anchor:hover {color:blue;}
    `]
})
export class TestApp{
    @Input() anchorClass: string;
}
```

Parent HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test">
        <testapp [anchorClass]="'red-green-anchor'"></testapp>  
    </div>
</div>
```

The way you are trying to do it is tightly coupling the parent with the child, not keeping everything self contained. Moving the styles to the child keeps the child self contained and any parents can decide which child css class to set keeping everything self contained.

[working plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/hJEy2Ddpy9V77BDAwRGw)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what i'm implementing is, I have a table div, when the user hovers over the div, the <td> color changes, when the user hovers over the <td> both the color and background color changes again. I've made the necessary changes in Plunker. http://plnkr.co/edit/gwcTi4QyZyFPtlgfY5Al?p=preview , it would be great, if you can tell me how to implement that. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, use (mouseover)="someFunction()" in your parent div and in your parent component implement someFunction() which sets the class of the parent, and the class of the child as in my answer. Don't 'hardcode' the class names, set them dynamically with ngClass in someFunction()

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you can use the pseudo elements (hover) with with Angular2.

But you can make your own directive to change the styling while hovering.
Check out this tutorial which adds an attribute directive for highlighting over hover.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html#!#respond-to-user

Comment: The hover for Anchor tag works in Angular 2. My question will work if `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` is added to Parent Component, but it changes all the styling. I'm asking if anyone knows any other solution?